# Alternate of facebook authentication dialogue box in iPhone using HTML5 and js(web app)

Tags: iphone, mobile, web, fbconnect, fbjs

i am able to authenticate a fb user by opening a new window, so it can post on his wall. I am using HTML 5 web app in order to make it but my share button doesn't work in iPhone. It doesn't open a new window.

I need it in the way that clicking on share button opens a dialogue box(not new window) on the same page and user share image etc. I saw an application which does so but that one is native iPhone app, but i want it using web tools HTML 5 js.

Any help will be highly admired.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen Facebook shares in iframes, and that may help you. For an example, try doing a Facebook share on LivingSocial -- they use iframes rather than new windows for the action. (ex. http://www.livingsocial.com/cities/9-philadelphia/deals/364564-20-to-spend-on-mexican-fare)